# Why can I not find this resources after Proguard Obfuscation?

Tags: java, obfuscation

after Proguard Obfuscation could not find resource from jar, 
i get following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mypackege.MyClass
```

Comment: The class have been obfuscated(renamed)...

Comment: Yes, It work fine, But give above error

Comment: Could you provide more details : The complete stack trace, the use case. The class mypackege.MyClass  is in the obfuscated jar ?

Comment: Once a the name of a class or method has been obfuscated, you can't use its old name. e.g. via reflections.

Comment: is is possible to obfuscate resources according to classes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be Found on  [Link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/ant.html)

`<adaptresourcefilenames filter = "file_filter" />` 
    `Rename the specified resource files, based on the obfuscated names of the corresponding class files.`

`<adaptresourcefilecontents filter = "file_filter" />` 
`Update the contents of the specified resource files, based on the obfuscated names of the processed classes.`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we have to define ofuscas classes and methods that do not want to be ofusquen because they will be called from outside the jar

Example for ant:

```
<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties"
         classpath="/usr/local/java/proguard/lib/proguard.jar" />
<proguard>
  -libraryjars ${java.home}/lib/rt.jar
  -injars      in.jar
  -outjars     out.jar

  -keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  }
</proguard>
```

More info: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/ant.html

Regards,